# Acentuação com problemas no servidor mais atualizado

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, yii

Tenho 2 servidores com as seguintes configurações:

**Servidor 1:**

> PHP 5.3.10
>   Apache 2.2.22
>   MySql 5.5.43
>   Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

**Servidor 2:**

> PHP 5.6.9
>   Apache 2.4.7
>   MySql 5.5.43
>   Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Estou a utilizar a framework Yii.

O problema é que no servidor 1 a palavra "cão" aparece normalmente, no servidor 2 aparece "cÃµo".

O servidor 2 é uma cópia do servidor 1 porém alteramos o Apache/PHP/SO.

Qual poderá ser a origem do problema? A versão do sistema operacional?

Comment: Da uma olhada no default_charset que fica dentro do php.ini dos dois servidores e verifica se os dois estão iguais.

Comment: @rdehnhardt sim, é igual. Nós alteramos porque por padrão o valor para o PHP 5.3 é diferente do PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que esteja usando o Yii versão 2.x, verifique no arquivo de configuração do banco (`config/db.php`) se está setado o charset como utf-8:

```
return [
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banco', 
   'username' => 'root', 
   'password' => '', 
   'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Verifique também no arquivo de layout ou nas views, se está setado o charset UTF-8.